# storing csv data in python list and accessing through list indices

Tags: python

I have a csv file with 1000000 records, having data as below:

```
age zipcode salary  occupation
33  2139    1001    'Financial analyst'
65  2139    1060    'Shoemaker'
46  2139    1061    'Domestic worker'
38  2140    1003    'Vicar'
54  2140    1029    'Mason'
44  2139    1002    'Philosopher'
```

I want to store it in a list Gtable using Python as below, I want to read a csv file(testReading.csv) in Gtable variable, which further i can access via Gtable[0] and Gtable[1].

How will i do this in Python, please guide, Thankyou all.

```
Gtable =  [[age],[zipcode],[salary],[occupation]]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into - https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
Hope this helps-

```
import csv
datafile = open('testReading.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=';')
Gtable = []
for row in datareader:
    Gtable.append(row)    
for row in Gtable:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you Abhisek Roy, it is printing the data in complete horizontal line, data in csv file hase 4 columns and 100000 rows, i want to priint that vertically also how to access different indices of Gtable, thankyou. And can you please give me your email or skype id ?

Comment: Thankyou @Abhisek Roy.